# SEF url without name with core php and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, sef

I want to make SEF url In that i want to remove file name also from the url.
my site is in the core php, I manage to remove the extension from the url but didn't have idea that how to remove the whole file name from the url.

As i searched on google i got this code for the .htaccess

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have no idea that how to write header in php so it goes in related file but don't show the file name in url.

```
    <a href='http://mysite.com/edit/user/2/1'>click</a>
```

Now if i click on above link it does goto edit.php with url "mysite.com/edit/user/2/1",

so from this how can i remove file name that is "edit".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Isn't that a SEO friendly and user friendly URL? Why would you want to make it un-user fiendly? But anyway my guess is that you want `/user` to point to `/edit` by the looks of it:

```
RewriteRule ^/?user/*$ /edit.php?type=user&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Though you will be making your site worse by using this and adding uneeded complexity to not only site maintenance but also user navigation.

Comment: I tired it but it didn't worked... my htaccess looks like as you said and the linke is "<a href='http://108.166.92.199/edit.php?type=user'>click</a>" and the url i get is also the same that is http://108.166.92.199/edit.php?type=user

Comment: @Satish Wait, what are you trying to do? Your question state you are trying to take `edit` out of `edit/user/2/1` but your comment says otherwise...so what ARE you trying to do? Are you actually trying to change `edit.php?type=user` into `/edit/user` ?

Comment: No I just want to remove edit.. so final url become like "mysite.com/user/otherquery string"

Comment: @Satish Then change your HTML link to go: `108.166.92.199/user/blah` and you should see some magic happen.

Comment: I did it but page not found error.. and other thing is that i want to do it for all the files of the site i want to remove all the filename from url..

Comment: @Satish I forgot all about this question, did you find the answer?

Comment: yes your answer is correct and I got the solution I was looking for.. Thanks for your time