# How to change URL in core PHP

Tags: php

How to change URL in core PHP? Please let me know how to do this

```
http://localhost/files/rajfireworks/product_details?pro_id=2
```

to

```
http://localhost/files/rajfireworks/product_details/productname
```

Comment: try with .htaccess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899769/sef-url-without-name-with-core-php-and-htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache rewrite - clean URLs in localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211824/apache-rewrite-clean-urls-in-localhost)

Answer (score 1):

This can help you:

Write below code in your .htaccess file.

**For inner page write:**
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+) product_details.php?name=$1 [NC]

**For all product page:**
RewriteRule ^products products.php [NC]

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['pro_id'])) {
  header("Location: /files/rajfireworks/product_details/productname");
}    
?>
```

Depends on `product_id` number - you can extend your conditions.

Comment: thanks for reply, pro_id is fetching dynamically.                                          <a href="product_details?pro_id=<?php echo $pro_details['p_id']; ?>" class="hover-cart">MORE <span>DETAILS</span></a>

Answer (score 0):

You can Use URL rewrite in htaccess File.

Put .htaccess file in main folder and use below code.It will read like if your URL **http://example.com/index.php?page=search** it will show like this  **http://example.com/search**

Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?cat=(search)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(search)$ /product.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add the following to your .htaccess:--

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)\.html$ /test/test.php?pagetitle=$1 [L]
```